# Dynamic Programming - Difficult Jumping Frog Problem

Tags: algorithms, dynamic-programming, python

Given a set of $n$ stones, arranged in a row at equal distances from each other. The stones are numbered from $0$ to $n-1$. A frog that is on stone number $0$ has to get to stone number $n-1$.

A jump is a move from stone $i$ to stone $j$ ($i<j$). Such a jump has length equal to $j-i$. The maximum jump length of the frog depends on its energy level (which cannot drop below $0$). A jump of length $j-i$ costs the frog $j-i$ energy. For example, with an initial energy of $3$, a frog on stone $0$ can jump to stone $3$ at most.

On some stones, there may be worms, which add energy to the frog. If the frog jumps on a stone with a worm on it, it MUST eat the worm. The list $T[0...n-1]$ contains the energy values of the worms on the corresponding stones. If there is no worm on the stone, this is equivalent to a value of $0$.

The frog starts with $0$ Energy, but it is guaranteed that there is a worm on stone number $0$.

Given a list $T$, the task is to return a list of the indexes of the stones on which the frog has been, before getting to stone $n-1$. However, this must be the shortest possible list. In some cases there may be more than one solution, whichever is accepted. It is guaranteed that always the frog will be able to get to stone $n-1$.

Example no. 1:
For $T = [3, 0, 2, 1, 0, 2, 5, 0]$
the answer is $[0, 2, 5]$.

Example no. 2:
For $T = [7, 0, 0, 1, 0, 3, 0, 6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]$
the answer is $[0, 5, 7]$.

I have no idea how to approach this problem, all I know is that I probably need to use dynamic programming here, but how? Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: https://cs.stackexchange.com/tags/dynamic-programming/info

Comment: Cross-posted: https://stackoverflow.com/q/72033038/781723, https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/151032/755.  Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068).

Answer (score 0):

Dynamic programming is about how to implement a problem, but I think you need to solve the problem first.

A good way to solve problems in this nature is with recursion, which to solve the problem, we should try to define it recursively first.

You can think of defining this recurrence as

f(stoneIndex, energy) -> which stones can we jump to, given the food on stoneIndex, and our energy level?

In terms of implementation, this should follow pretty quickly from the recurrence. To do DP, just cache calls to f()

Comment: I realise that I need to find a recursive function first, but I don't know what it would look like. Well, it is not enough to simply find the set of stones on which the frog was, it still has to be the shortest one possible, which complicates things a lot.

Answer (score 0):

We shall use bottom-up dynamic programming, where subproblems of smallest size are solved first, and their solutions are used to update the solutions to larger subproblems.  Let $A$ be a two-dimensional array, where $A[e,i]$ denotes the minimum number of jumps needed to reach the $i$-th stone with an energy of $e$ (after consuming the worm at stone $i$).  Thus, if $T= [7,0,0,1,0,3,0,6,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]$, then $A[7,0]=0$ because you reached stone $0$ after $0$ jumps, and the energy level after reaching stone $0$ and consuming the worm at that stone is $7$.  (When you work this out in paper, you can draw a 2D grid of $A[e,i]$ values in (say) the first-quadrant of the x-y plane).

The algorithm can iterate over the indices $i$, as they go from $0$ to $n-2$. For each value of $i$, find all the energy levels $e$ that are attained by various paths that reach that stone, and for each such pair of indices $(e,i)$ where a value has been set, use the current value of $A[e,i]$ to update the values of $A[e',i']$ for all feasible $(e',i')$.  The feasible values of $(e',i')$ are those where the jump size $i'-i$ is in $\{1,2,\ldots,e\}$ and $e' = e - (i'-i) + T[i']$ because you start with energy level $e$, consume energy $i'-i$ to make the jump, and consume energy $T[i']$ at stone $i'$.  If $A[e',i']$ is already at most $A[e,i]+1$, then don't do anything, otherwise reduce its value to $A[e,i]+1$ because a shorter path has been found. (When reducing the value, also update the parent pointer, like we usually do with dynamic programming algorithms, so that an optimal solution can be recovered later.)

For example, when $i=0$, the only pair $(e,i)$ for which a value has been set is $(7,0)$, for which $A[7,0]=0$.  With this current energy level of 7 at stone 0, a 1-jump gives $A[6,1]=1$, a 2-jump gives $A[5,2]=1$, a 3-jump gives $A[5,3]=1$ (note that it is $A[5,3]$, not $A[4,3]$ that is set to 1, because the worm of energy 1 is consumed at position 3, increasing the energy level by 1), a 4-jump gives $A[3,4]=1$, a 5-jump gives $A[5,5]=1$, a 6-jump gives $A[1,6]=1$, and a 7-jump $A[6,7]=1$. Then, one proceeds to $i=1$ and updates values of $A[e,j]$ for $j > 1$.  You'll notice that when you get to $i=5$ (say), the values of $A[5,5]$ and $A[6,5]$ have been set to 1 and 2, respectively, because it's possible to reach stone 5 using a single jump and energy level 5, or using two jumps and energy level 6.

At the end of iteration $i=n-2$, the algorithm would have the shortest path to stone $n-1$.

Comment: Did I understand you correctly, our two-dimensional array has size $A[0...T[0]][0...n-1]$?
How would it work if we collected more than $T[0]$ energy at some point?

Comment: Should I rather find that E is the highest possible energy level we can achieve? And then the size of the array is $A[0...E][0...n-1]$? Only I am afraid that in this case the size of the array can be sometimes very large.

Comment: And if I understand correctly, if no value is set in $A[e′,i′]$, we also assign it $A[e,i]+1$?

Comment: @PK96 As the energy levels increase to e’, you just insert more elements into a dynamically sized list d[i’]. In Python, d could be a dictionary and d[i’] would contain a list of elements of the form [e’,A[e’,i’]], say.  In C, you can use an array of n linked lists.  That way you don’t need to declare max length of d[i’] at compile time.

Comment: If no value is set for A[e’,i’], then you don’t consider this pair (e’,i’) during iteration i’ because it would not appear in the corresponding linked list.

Comment: Which programming language do you plan to use?

Comment: I have to use python, but I cannot use advanced structs like dictionaries, these are the conditions of the assignment.

Comment: Although I can use deque and priority queue.

Comment: But there is no value set at the beginning anywhere except A[7][0] for the second example so there will always be no value for A[e'][i'], or have I misunderstood you on something.

Comment: Correct, initially the other dictionaries d[i’] for i’>1 would be empty.

Comment: In Python, you can create a list of dictionaries, where the i’ th dictionary L[i’] would have the various e’ values as key.  If you are not allowed to use a dictionary, just create a list L of sub lists. L[i’] is a sublist of [e’, A[e’,i’]] values.

Comment: "Correct, initially the other dictionaries d[i’] for i’>1 would be empty" And that is not a problem? Then I guess I don't understand how updating $A[e′,i′]$ works. Then in what case do we assign $A[e,i]+1$ to $A[e′,i′]$?

Comment: If e’ is already present in the i’ th dictionary or sublist, then update its value if a shorter path was found.  Otherwise add a new key-value pair (e’,i’) pair to the i’ th dictionary or sublist.

Comment: I have written a program and let's say I have generated some values in the array A, but what next? Because in A I have stored the number of jumps needed to get to the i-th stone at energy level e, how can I interpret this to get the path?

Comment: Think about it. Store parent pointers.

Comment: Indeed the solution works, but for relatively small array T. For T of size 1000 the algorithm already fails, and should give an answer even for T of size 100000

Comment: @PK96 fails means? Is it due to storage space or time complexity?